# conda environments in team and shared Linux environment - best practices?

Tags: python, conda, sdlc, mamba

Conda is great, but it assumes that people code completely independently much like the complete lack of namespace hierarchy in public python modules. Looking for best practices with 6 people all developing in largely the same conda environment. Let's pretend there won't be exceptions. No containers, which would make this easier.

I want to ask others what tips other have? Any other best practices anyone can recommend?

Here's what we are working on currently:

1. Having a "source" environment.yml and then having all developers work from an exported snapshot yml (unless they are developing the conda environment itself) so they are all developing in the exact same environment. you don't want surprises when someone's app goes to prod and you find out the environment it was developed under. This is just standard best practice in every language.
2. Deploying shared conda environments to QA and Prod. Conda environments take up several GB of space, which is a minor concern, but it also takes a lot of time to install. It's a lot of machinery to install for every application update. Yes, need to be concerned about versioning that conda environment, but it is a less a problem to have 2 or 3 versions in use at the same time. And yes, there are occasionally bugs in conda/mamba. It's a pain to work around them

Comment: We have been using `conda` for years, and found [`conda-pack`](https://conda.github.io/conda-pack/) to be very helpful when deploying reproducible conda environments to other machines. It makes unpacking quite fast.

Comment: "Best practice" questions are generally off-topic here, being eligible for close as either too-broad or opinion-based. Consider the software engineering Stack Exchange site instead, [programmers.se]

Comment: That said, _personally_, I'd ditch Conda in favor of [Nix](https://nixos.org/) (which is not at all specific to the Python ecosystem and lets you manage software written in _any_ language with similar facility).

Comment: Using [`conda-lock`](https://conda.github.io/conda-lock/) should improve your reproducibility and would eliminate solve times (everything is pre-solved to stable URLs).

Comment: I just got a conda-pack deployment working as part of an ecosystem of another dozen tools. I do like the conda-pack deployment. Really easy to debug in situ without requiring conda to deployed in the target environment

Answer (score 2):

Been using conda for a couple of years but lately abandoned it after it put my team into deadlock situations a couple of times.

First suggestion I'd give, if you want to remain in the conda system, is at least to switch to mamba, since conda at times can be exceedingly slow.

You did not specify what environment/languages you need to manage.

For my team it's 95% python, and we switched to poetry which we find a lot faster, and makes it easier to manage a consistent environment via its TOML config. We use it also to separate the productions project dependencies from the development env, where the latter is equipped with many linters/testers etc used in either local (eg pre-commit) or remote (eg github actions) workflows.

Of course if you'd need to install non python stuff that is not on PyPI, either conda or your platform's package managers (eg homebrew for Mac, apt for Debian Linux and derivatives) will be necessary.

Hope any of this is useful.

Comment: If you host your own conda channels on S3, mamba doesn't (yet) work with those.

Comment: Thank you very, very much - very helpful! This repo I'm managing is all python with some bash. The larger team is all C++.  On the dev env, we've done similar with Dockerfiles (on a different team) and I see the value of having the linters and formatters separate as ours is getting bloated already. I will get there eventually.

Comment: @SeanBlanton Slight learning curve with poetry playing strange with visual studio initially but now that things are ironed out I am extremely satisfied.